How can I get useFetch to trigger when NuxtLink is clicked?
The issue is that my view is not re-rendering nor is useFetch re-running when a pagination link is clicked. I suspect this is something to do with data reactivity in Nuxt - which is new to me.
I have this as my script.
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
const { data, status, error, refresh } = await useFetch("/api/search", {
  query: useRoute().query,
});

const page_options = [10, 25, 50, 100];
</script>

The page renders correctly and processes the URL query params of q, per_page and page.
I have an array of links to navigate to the search URL with an updated page param.
 <NuxtLink
          :class="{
            'p-2 border-2': true,
            'bg-pink-800 text-white': index === Number(data.pagination.page),
          }"
          v-for="index in data.pagination.page_count"
          :key="index"
          :to="{
            name: 'archive-search',
            query: {
              per_page: data.pagination.per_page,
              page: index,
              q: route.query.q,
            },
          }"
        >
          {{ index }}
        </NuxtLink>

The URL updates but nothing is trigger either server side or client side. I suspect this is something to do with watching a value but how is this best done with url params?
Cheers.

According to the official documents of Nuxt, all fetch options can be given a computed or ref value. These will be watched and new requests made automatically with any new values if they are updated.
useRoute().query is not a ref. You can wrap it in a toRef or computed to trigger refetch.
const route = useRoute();
const query = computed(()=>{
  return route.query
});
const { data, status, error, refresh } = await useFetch("/api/search", {
  query,
});

Ref: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#params
